# Is it possible to cache IEnumerable lazy evaluation results?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, lazy-evaluation

I'm working on a method to find a config file path. This needs to do two passes: first find any existing config files, then go backwards and find the first writable path.

Though overkill for my particular situation, this got me thinking: is it possible to have both lazy evaluation and prevent multiple enumeration?

To illustrate what I mean, consider the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetPaths()
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetPaths() Returning 'one'");
    yield return "one";
    Console.WriteLine("GetPaths() Returning 'two'");
    yield return "two";
    Console.WriteLine("GetPaths() Returning 'three'");
    yield return "three";
}

public bool IsWritable(string path) => false; // testing only
```

If I run:

```
var paths = GetPaths();
Console.WriteLine("Searching for existing file..");
foreach (var path in paths)
{
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Found existing file '{path}'");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Searching for a writable path..");
foreach (var path in paths.Reverse()) // NOTE: paths enumarated twice
{
    if (IsWritable(path))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Found writable path '{path}'");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("No paths found");
```

If the file 'one' exists, we get:

```
Searching for existing file..
Returning 'one'
Found existing file 'one'
```

If however, no files exist, we get:

```
Searching for existing file..
Returning 'one'
Returning 'two'
Returning 'three'
Searching for a writable path..
Returning 'one'
Returning 'two'
Returning 'three'
No paths found
```

(we wastefully enumerate the results of GetPaths() twice)

---

One simple fix is to change the first line to:

```
var paths = GetPaths().ToList();
```

However, that means that even if the file `one` exists, the output would be:

```
Returning 'one'
Returning 'two'
Returning 'three'
Searching for existing file..
Found existing file 'one'
```

(as in, we unnecessarily enumerate the remainder of the list)

---

Is there a (built-in) way to get both lazy enumeration and still prevent multiple enumeration?

In other words, the desired output when 'one' exists is:

```
Searching for existing file..
Returning 'one'
Found existing file 'one'
```

and if no files exist:

```
Searching for existing file..
Returning 'one'
Returning 'two'
Returning 'three'
Searching for a writable path..
No paths found
```

Comment: Yes.  Call `ToArray` on the enumerable.

Comment: I don't believe there's anything built-in for this, no. You could implement it yourself, but that's a different matter.

Comment: @Will: In what way is that still lazy? That's equivalent (in terms of evaluation) to calling `ToList()` which the OP has already explained...

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question, but; What if you extend it with `var paths = paths.Where(file => File.Exists(path));`? It will still be lazy...

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen that would still result in a second evaluation if no files exist.

Comment: I do not understand your question..

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Updated question to show desired output. In this case I need to evaluate the results twice (the second time in reverse), with different criteria. I also can't optimize to do a single pass, because finding out if the file is writable is a side-effecting operation (that is, it modifies the file system).

Comment: @JonSkeet I evaluated his question lazily, I guess.  "Caching" an IEnumerable suggests saving the result rather than re-evaluating it every time you access it.

Comment: I think what you want is called memoization. I dont have a solution right now, but I have always wanted one myself and certainly doable. You could write an extestion method which returns a type that lazily evaluates and at the same time stores results once iterated. I will write an answer later, or search "memoiz"

Comment: about the piece of code `If the file 'one' exists, we get:` the iteration isn't broken, so it will iterate more? It will always say: `Console.WriteLine("No paths found");`

Answer (score 1):

This is not built-in in the sense of being part of .NET, but it is "off-the-shelf".

Use Nuget to install [morelinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) ([package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/)).

Then add

```
using MoreLinq.Experimental;
```

Change the example to:

```
var paths = GetPaths().Memoize();
```

And it will produce the desired output.

Note that morelinq does consider [`Memoize`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.3/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_Experimental_ExperimentalEnumerable_Memoize__1.htm) to be "experimental", FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. If the Enumerator returned by your Lazy call gets its data in turn from the same instance of an underlying data provider, and that provider tracks each item it yields, then all instance of the Enumerator are actually pulling data from the same instance of the data provider.

Consider an Enumerator to return lines from a file; if that Enumerator shared the same Stream instance with all other enumerators for that file then you would get the behaviour you are illustrating.

In pseudo-code

```
static System.IO.FileStream fs;
private static void GetFileStream()
{
    if(fs == null) fs = System.IO.File.Open(....);
    return fs;
}

public Enumarable<string> GetLines()
{
    // return an enumerator that uses the result of GetFileStream() and 
    // advances the file pointer. All Enumerables returned by this method
    // will return unique lines from the same file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have missed something, but why not use System.Linq.Enumerable's [FirstOrDefault](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,956) extension method?

```
    public static bool IsWritable(string path)
    {
        Func<string, bool> canBeWrittenTo = p => true;// (details omitted)
        return System.IO.File.Exists(path) && canBeWrittenTo(path);
    }
```

Then:

```
        var firstWritablePath = GetPaths().FirstOrDefault(path => IsWritable(path));
        if (firstWritablePath != null)
        {
            // Found existing file...
        }
        else
        {
            // No paths found...
        }
```